# Which countries other than India can I exchange Indian Rupees?

Tags: money

I was surprised that in Nepal I couldn't exchange Indian Rupees for any other currency. Are there any countries (other than India) that allow exchanging of Indian Rupees?

Comment: Legally, you are not allowed to take Rupies in cash out of India (or bring them in). That might explain it. Of course, this law is mostly ignored by many travelers.

Comment: Are you talking about the old currency that has been demonetized or the new ones?

Comment: @PSC775 The Indian currency has not been demonetized, but older bank notes have been withdrawn from circulation and invalidated. Not that it matters at all for this question, but that are two completely different issues.

Comment: UAE allows you to exchange indian rupees.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The word "currency" is used to refer both to the coins and banknotes and the system of money. PSC775 is clearly referring to (some of) the banknotes, not the Indian Rupee as a system of money.